# How to upload 14Gb to OneDrive?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I am wondering is there a bulk uploader or something that I can use to upload 14GB of mp3s, pictures and text documents.

Pics and Mp3s make about 12.5GB of it. I am using windows 8.1 and put all the files in the OneDrive folder but it seems so slow, It seems like it will take a few weeks running 24/7 to actually upload all this data what is sad.

I am hoping there is a better way. I am starting out with OneDrive so I would they would anticipate people moving all their pics and stuff to the OneDrive then syncing everything else on demand once generated.

Comment: What's your internet connection upload speed? I would not be surprised if it took a week or so of 24/7 uploading over the average internet connection in the US.

Comment: 5mbps...which seems like it should be about 7 to 8 hours. I not sure what it is actually transferring at though, I am not also sure if my computer just goes to sleep(though I disabled sleep option) and that it stops uploading as I walked about from my computer for a few hours and it seemed like it stopped uploading.

Comment: run a speedtest at http://www.speedtest.net/ (wait for the "begin test" button, the ads on that page often try to trick you with fake buttons) and tell us what your UPLOAD speed is (the second test).

Comment: Ya, I can run a speed test but I mean I don't know what skydrive is actually doing(I don't if it limits the speed or what)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bulk upload to Skydrive?](http://superuser.com/questions/190090/bulk-upload-to-skydrive)

Comment: Try the Windows Store app to see if that will keep it moving. But I have the same upspeed and also just copy to my folder in Windows, and it takes about as long as we'd calculate it to take. Checkout how much data you're uploading per second in Task Manager as well, maybe it just seems slow.

Answer (score 1):

15032385536 Data bytes (14GB) @ a max speed of 5000000 bps
500000 Bytes / sec approximate MAX

30064.771072    seconds TOTAL
501.0795178667  minutes TOTAL
8.3513252978    hours   TOTAL

08:25:55    h:m.s, optimistic time spent, expect something between the double and this, at best. (50%-75% efficiency)

Experience-based opinion:
If you're on any a/vDSL variant (not fiber) then the speed may vary, even more if it is wireless.

Comment: I'm guessing that onedrive will only use a small percentage of whatever his available upstream bandwidth is. Designed that way to avoid complaints of slowing other things down.

Comment: Probably, yes. And also reducing the need for a multitude of servers with huge performance.

Comment: since they now change $2.50 US for 1TB they are going to need alot of huge performance servers =] (and an office365 subscriber gets 5tb total automatically)

Answer (score -1):

I have been having same issues but have stumbled across a fix which I don't understand. I have about 6Gb of data on my OneDrive and initial upload was going to take a week or more. However, if I change the location of my "documents" library to point to OneDrive and store my data in this documents library rather than adressing the OneDrive directly, the upload speed is considerably faster - 6Gb in about 6 hours. I have no idea why this should make a difference but it does.....